# Shopify: How to add a button link to Amazon listing based on the current product page?

Tags: html, url, button, shopify, liquid

Using one of the free Shopify templates ("Refresh"), I want to add a 3rd button below the default add to cart and buy button that says "Buy on Amazon" and links to the Amazon listing of the same product.

To make it look natural with the theme, I was able to "Add Block" on the product page called "Custom Liquid" which allows me to put in some code to make a button with a custom link. But this will be the same link for every product, how would I be able to base the URL on the current product page that a customer is viewing?

Current code:
`{{ 'Buy on Amazon' | link_to: 'my-URL', class: 'button' }}`

-

I tried to find a way to tag each Amazon URL to each product in the Shopify products data section but there is not option.

I read some of the Liquid documentation and see that there are 'objects' for products and that you can call them up using handles and return tags. But I do not know how to correctly associate each URL to each product within the code, nor do I know how to retrieve that URL based on the current product page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my detailed blog for this issue https://inittasker.com/boost-your-shopify-store-integrate-amazon-product-urls-for-every-product/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).